# When will I be able to translate Facebook?

Tags: facebook, translation

I want to translate Facebook to languages I speak on a daily basis, and it says that I need to be a user on Facebook for a defined period of time before I'll be able to translate the website, but it's not mentioning the how much.

When will I be able to translate Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the Translations app and choose your language.

[Source](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2008/04/02/now-you-can-help-translate-facebook-into-any-language/)

Looking at the page for the [Translations app](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4329892722&v=info) it's not clear what you need to do to get your language added, but it does state:

> Add the Translations Application to translate, review and vote on translations in your language.

So the first step would be to add the application and see what options are available to you.

I can't comment further as my language - English - is fully translated:

> The Translation Application is currently closed for Facebook in English (UK). Please check back later.